# oracle sql: not able to add foreign key to table -> invalid identifier?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

First off, I'm a real newbie to db and sql. However, I have to tables, PERSON and SPECIES and I want to add a foreign key to the table SPECIES. When trying to add the foreign key I always get the error message "ORA-900904: invalid identifier". I just can't figure out what I've done wrong and why it doesn't work?!?!

This was my approach:

**PERSON table and primary key**

```
create table person
(
name varchar2 (30),
firstname varchar2 (30),
persid number (8) not null
)
;

alter table person 
add constraint person_pk 
primary key (persid)
;
```

**SPECIES table and primary key**

```
create table species
(
speciesnamelat varchar2 (30),
vartid number (8) not null
)
;

alter table Species
add constraint species_pk
primary key (vartid)
;
```

This part worked fine but the following didn't work:

**Foreign Key for SPECIES referring to PERSON**

```
alter table species
add constraint species_person_fk
foreign key (persid)
references person (persid)
;
```

I always get this Error "ORA-900904: invalid identifier"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are refereing to `persid` which is not a column in table `species` thus the error...

EDIT - As per comments:

It means that you need some column in `species` to be used as foreign key... if there is no such column then you need to build one in before you can create that constraint.  Like this:

```
alter table species
add persid number(8) not null
;
alter table species
add constraint species_person_fk
foreign key (persid)
references person (persid)
;
```

Depending on your data model, SPECIES.PERSID may be optional or mandatory.

Comment: does that mean I need to build in the attribute in the species table beforehand?

Comment: @samjam yes, it means that you need some column in `species` to be used as foreign key... if there is no such column then you need build one in before you can create that constraint.